# Como recuperar Actividade, em vez de criar nova, quando clicar na notificação?

Tags: android, android-notification

Na minha app quando actividade vai para o estado *onPause* faço disparar as notificações dela através do NotificationManager.
Pretendia que ela pudesse ser recuperada para o estado *onResume* caso fosse dado um *click* na notificação.
Através deste código consigo abrir uma nova actividade, mas o que eu pretendia era antes recuperar a actividade que está no estado *onPause*:

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)  getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class), 0);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this);
builder.setTicker("Tiker Valor: "+Integer.toString(i));
builder.setContentTitle("Titulo Valor: "+Integer.toString(i));
builder.setContentText("Descrição");
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
builder.setContentIntent(p);

Notification n = builder.build();
n.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;// Retira a notificação quando esta for clicada
nm.notify(R.drawable.ic_launcher, n);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No *AndroidManifest.xml*, na declaração da actividade, coloque:

```
<activity
    android:name="........
    ............
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    ......
    ......>
</activity>
```

Ou *set* as *flags* `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` e `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` no Intent usado para lançar a Activity:

```
...
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
...
```

Comment: ramaral, funcionou. Obrigado. Abraço.